# Finding the time of a thumbnail in a video

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I have a large set of pre-generated thumbnails and videos. **What is the easiest way to figure out the specific time in the video of the associated thumbnail?**

I'd imagine that I would have to use something to loop through all the frames in a video to find a match. What libraries should I use? Something like OpenCV maybe? ffmpeg?

Python is preferred but not required.

Comment: My idea is first match the thumbnail with a key-frame, the match it with frames related to that key-frame. That should reduce the number of comparison a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenCV can do the trick. E.g.(C++):

```
    Mat thumbnail=imread("./mythumb.jpg");
    VideoCapture capture("./myvideo.avi");
    Mat frame;
    double max_score=0;
    int best_matching_frame=-1;
    int framenum=0;
    while (true){
        if (!capture.read(frame)) break;
        double score=comparefunction(thumbnail,frame);
        if (score>max_score) {
          best_matching_frame=framenum;
          max_score=score;
        }
        framenum++;
    }
```

You'll have to find an implementation for the `comparefunction()`. Search stackoverflow how to compare images.

Comment: I know of OpenCV and have played around with the Python bindings, but I'm not that familiar with it. How CPU intensive is this kind of operation? How would you expect it to perform on, let's say, thousands of videos? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Liam, that would be very slow and not guaranteed to give exact frame in all conditions. In static scenes several frames could match. If you are creating the thumbnails in the first place, adding some userdata might help there.